# Transform an array of objects in an object list with a property of the object as key

Tags: javascript, arrays, object, ecmascript-6

I have an array of objects and I would like to transform it in an object with objects where the object keys are one of the properties of the object, like:

Example of the original array:

```
const myArray = [
  {"groupName":"groupname","description":"nice description here","name":"name1","value":107},
  {"groupName":"groupname","description":"nice description here","name":"name1","value":107}
]
```

Using es6 nice new features the Object.assign is very close to what I need but it assigns numeric keys to the objects, like:

```
let newObject = Object.assign({}, myArray);
```

This gives me a very close object like:

```
{
  "0": {"groupName":"groupname","description":"nice description here","name":"name1","value":107},
  "1": {"groupName":"groupname","description":"nice description here","name":"name1","value":107}
}
```

But what I really need is to have one of the properties of the object as key instead of the assigned numbers, like:

```
{
  "name1": {"groupName":"groupname","description":"nice description here","name":"name1","value":107},
  "name2": {"groupName":"groupname","description":"nice description here","name":"name2","value":107}
}
```

I can iterate and create the object but after using the Object.assign that gives a one liner very close solution I am wondering if there's a way in es6 to do the same without iterate using forEach or a map.

Ideas?

Comment: Are you sure there is no duplicate names? If so then some objects will be lost.

Comment: @ibrahimmahrir I understand but yes, in the real case there are no duplicate names. Tx for the warning anyway!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To convert the array into an object with a specific value as a key, you'll need to iterate the array, and build the objects' properties.

---

Use [Array#reduce](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/Reduce) to "manually" add properties to an object:

```js
const myArray = [{"groupName":"groupname","description":"nice description here","name":"name1","value":107}, {"groupName":"groupname","description":"nice description here","name":"name2","value":107}]

const result = myArray.reduce((r, o) => (r[o.name] = o, r), {});

console.log(result);
```

### **Or**

---

Use [Array#map](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map) to wrap each object in an object with a key, and then combine them to single object using [Object#assign](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/assign) and [spread](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Spread_operator):

```js
const myArray = [{"groupName":"groupname","description":"nice description here","name":"name1","value":107}, {"groupName":"groupname","description":"nice description here","name":"name2","value":107}]

const result = Object.assign({}, ...myArray.map((o) => ({ [o.name]: o })));

console.log(result);
```

Answer (score 0):

Well, why a need of es6 and loops in form of map/reduce/forEach when simple manipulations can work.

```
let myArray = [
  {"groupName":"groupname","description":"nice description here","name":"name1","value":107},
  {"groupName":"groupname","description":"nice description here","name":"name2","value":108}
]
let newObject ={};
newObject[myArray[0].name] = myArray[0];
newObject[myArray[1].name] = myArray[1];
console.log(newObject);
```

Comment: What if there is a zillion skillion (10^100000) entries in the array?

Comment: Point taken. I assumed the OP doesn't want to loop when he/she specified not to use forloop

Comment: @ibrahimmahrir we're going to need more RAM

Comment: @apokryfos That's inevitable. But with this solution you'll need more stamina and more hard drive storage too, to type and store those lines of code.